# discord.py TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, typeerror

I'm trying to write a discord bot that checks for the word "pawel" in every message sent and if it finds one, it should send a message to a discord text channel called #pawel. If there isn't one it should create it. Right now I'm stuck with this stupid error:

```
We're live!
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 22, in on_message
    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name='pawel')
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/utils.py", line 269, in get
    for elem in iterable:
TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable
```

The full code for the bot down here:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()
guild = discord.Guild

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We're live!")

pawel = ('pawel')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if pawel in message.content:
        channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name='pawel')
        channel.id = channel.id
        if channel == None:
            await guild.create.text_channel('pawel')
        await message.channel.send('pawel')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I've tried everything!

Answer (score 3):

I think that the issue here is that you're not actually getting an individual guild, but just producing a general Guild Object `guild = discord.Guild`
You can get the guild's text channels by doing
`message.guild.text_channels`

When adapted to your code it would result in:

```
channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.text_channels, name="pawel")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pawel = 'pawel'
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        if pawel in message.content:
            channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.text_channels, name = 'pawel')
            if channel is None:
                await guild.create_text_channel('pawel')
            await channel.send('pawel')
```

Kindly remove the `channel.id = channel.id` (as if the channel is none then channel.id will throw error 'None type object does not have attribute id', and frankly has no use here)

change the `guild.text_channel` to `message.guild_text_channels`.
Also it's `guild.create_text_channel` not `guild.create.text_channel`

I believe you wanted to send the message to the channel named pawel. In such a case, `message.channel.send` is inappropriate as it will send message to the channel which triggered the event. However, if this wasn't intended then you may leave it. (if it was intended like the way I described, use `channel.send` instead of that to send it to the channel named "pawel"

The above code was obtained after a few minutes of debugging from my side.
Just incase if you are confused about the `message.channel.send` and `channel.send` issue, I will leave the modified original code below this line.

Also you can use `is` for None type objects instead of `==`

```
pawel = 'pawel'
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        if pawel in message.content:
            channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.text_channels, name = 'pawel')
            if channel is None:
                await guild.create_text_channel('pawel')
            await message.channel.send('pawel')
```